# Date from string is not coming properly and two dates difference also using Swift 3?

Tags: ios, date, swift3, date-format, difference

I have a date in string format, example:- "2017-07-31" or can be multiple dates (any) in string format. My requirement is to check this date to current date and if it is greater than 0 and less than 15, then that time I have to do another operation.

So first I am converting that date string to in date format. But it is giving one day ago date. Here is my code:

```
//Date from string
func dateFromString(date : String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let currentDate = (dateFormatter.date(from: date))//(from: date))
    return currentDate!
}
```

Ex. my date is "2017-08-30"  and this function is returning 2017-08-29 18:30:00 +0000 in date format. It means 1 day ago. I am little bit confuse about dates operation. I read so many blogs also.

After that I have to check this date to current date if it is in between 0 < 15 than I will do other operation.

Comparing two dates:

```
extension Date {
  func daysBetweenDate(toDate: Date) -> Int {
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: toDate)
    return components.day ?? 0
  }
}
```

If my date is today date and comparing to tomorrow date then also it is giving 0 days difference. Why?

Comment: `2017-08-29 18:30:00 +0000` is *correct.* A Date has no timezone and is always printed in UTC. It is the *same date* as "2017-08-30" in your local time zone.

Comment: Ok but while comparing to current date it is weird. Its not giving proper difference. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with input data, expected output and actual output.

Comment: I just edited my question.
If I am comparing days.

Comment: @kishor0011 if you are comparing days then if the number of hours will be greater than 24 then only it will show a value greater than 0

Comment: you can count the number of seconds between two dates and then divide it accordingly to get number of days. ` var seconds = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: date1, to: date2!).second ?? 0`

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal then What should I do if my date is "2017-07-31" and I am comparing to dates "2017-07-30" and "2017-08-01" and It should give -1 and 1. Thanks

Comment: Where does the `daysBetween` method come from?

Comment: I am comparing current date to Other date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If – for example – the current date is 2017-07-31 at 11AM then the 
difference to 2017-08-01 (midnight) is 0 days and 13 hours, and that's
why you get "0 days difference" as result.

What you probably want is to compare the difference between the *start*
of the current day and the other date in days:

```
extension Date {
    func daysBetween(toDate: Date) -> Int {
        let cal = Calendar.current
        let startOfToday = cal.startOfDay(for: self)
        let startOfOtherDay = cal.startOfDay(for: toDate)
        return cal.dateComponents([.day], from: startOfToday, to: startOfOtherDay).day!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to explaining. It is working but I want to ask one thing that is current date will compare "2017-07-31" so there is already 24 hours difference to   2017-08-01 but it is giving 0 day. So u r using startOfDay?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for convert string to date:

```
func dateFromString(date : String) -> Date {
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
  dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC")
  let currentDate = (dateFormatter.date(from: date))//(from: date))
  return currentDate!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to compare the time between two dates in seconds :

```
  var seconds = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: date1!, to: date2!).second ?? 0

    seconds = abs(seconds)

    let min  = seconds/60     // this gives you the number of minutes between two dates
    let hours = seconds/3600  // this gives you the number of hours between two dates
    let days = seconds/3600*24  // this gives you the number of days between two dates
```

Comment: **NO.** – A day can have 23, 24, or 25 hours. Think of daylight saving time.

Comment: Yes, this can be an issue. Thanks for pointing out, so we can put the conditions accordingly